# How do I compile a program in code::blocks using C when it won't let me?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I don't know if is a very simple error becouse the last time I used code::blocks was like 2 years but when I try to build my (Very simple) program, nothing happends, just the build screen goes out and the program doesn't run.

(sorry for my stinky english, I usually talk spanish)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello!");





}
```

I closed the program and the complete PC but nothing happends.

I use C and my OS is a windows 10.

Comment: Your string is missing a newline to force it to flush the output buffer.

Comment: There's no errors in the build-log? Does a console window open and close very quickly?

Comment: @stark The output buffer should be flushed on program exit.

Comment: Have you tried compiling/running it in the terminal (`cmd`)?

Comment: Starting with all, Neil, I've tried to run in the terminal (cmd) the program code:: blokcs but the same message shows up, I will try to compile in the terminal but I think that the solutions is another.

When I open the program I saw a message that I didn't see the other day that said: "cannot find the compiler executable", I'm going To search in stack overflow, the solution to see if my program finally runs.

I didn't understand very well the comments of stark and some programer, but if the solution that I've said didn't run, I'll try to make the solution commented.

Comment: This is an update on my newest message, I've found that I downloaded a version that doesn't have, I'll download another time codeblocks but with the compiler executable.

Thanks for all the responses.